# Magento Admin Panel Broken

Tags: magento, admin

We were doing typical content edits and the admin panel had the regular functionality and styling. When we finished and logged out and then in again....We got just a file tree...the links withing the tree just loop back to the original page when you click on them... There is no way to edit anything...Please Help!

Using Magento ver. 1.5.1.0

We will pay someone to fix this issue...

Thank you!

james

SCREEN SHOT: http://goo.gl/nhaJS

Answer (score 0):

May be js file are  not working here. you can check file permission of js.